# Can I use a Dungeons of Dredmor expansion purchased through Steam in Desura?

Tags: steam, dungeons-of-dredmor, desura

I bought the Dungeons of Dredmor expansion, Realm of the Diggle Gods, on Steam. However, I prefer to play DoD on Linux, through Desura. Is there any way I can move the expansion to the Desura install, perhaps through copying some files over?

Comment: I heard the Desura staff is quite helpful and might unlock the content if you would send them proof of your Steam purchase. Unfortunately, at the time of writing it seems this DLC package is not yet available on Desura, so I doubt this solution is currently applicable. Copying some parts of the installation over might do the trick, but I am not sure it's 100% legal.

Comment: Maybe you saw it, but now Steam is available in beta-version on Linux

Comment: @cporte - Ah, I hadn't noticed that yet. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score -1):

Most of the time you can't interchange DLC bought through different DRM platforms. The possibility to swap the DLC files from one platform to another shouldn't be a trivial task in our times.

Maybe I'll have a look in the source file at home but I'm sure that it is nearly impossible if you are not a master in computer science^^

Comment: "Maybe I'll have a look in the source file at home but I'm sure that it is nearly impossible if you are not a master in computer science" - is this satire?

Comment: The last line is a joke mostly.